# Find which matrix row has values specified from array

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

How can I find which row in a matrix has a specified set values that I entered in an array?

So for example;

```
A = [4 5 6 7; 
     8 4 5 6;
     4 5 6 8;
     8 4 8 9;
     1 2 2 4;
     5 3 4 6];
```

and I want to find which row has the vector of `[4 5 6 8]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `all` and `find`...

With implicit expansion (R2016b or newer)

```
find( all( A == [4 5 6 8], 2 ) )
```

Equivalently you can use `bsxfun` (compatible with all MATLAB versions)

```
find( all( bsxfun( @eq, A, [4 5 6 8] ), 2 ) )
```

The output in both cases is `3` from your example `A`.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [@Wolfie's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54559671/2586922), assuming order matters.

Another possibility is to use [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html). This can be used both when order matters and when it doesn't. Let

```
A = [4 5 6 7; 8 4 5 6; 4 5 6 8; 8 4 8 9; 1 2 2 4; 5 3 4 6];
v = [4 5 6 8];
```

- If order matters:

  ```
  result = find(ismember(A, v, 'rows'));
  ```
- If order doesn't matter:

  ```
  result = find(all(ismember(A, v), 2));
  ```